# How to use *ng-If for validate empty array in Ionic 2

Tags: php, arrays, validation, frameworks, ionic2

I have a ng-if, I have a ng-for that shows me all the products I have, and I want to do in my ng if a validation that only shows when the array is empty or does not exist, this Is to display a message that products are not found on the page, Thank you! ;)

I try with **"!ProductsCar"** , but it does not work.

Code :

```html
<ion-list *ngFor="let productsCar of productsCar">
    <ion-item-sliding>
  <ion-item class="item-prod">
    <ion-thumbnail item-start>
         <img  src="https://speedomart.000webhostapp.com/SPEEDOMART/{{productsCar.imagen}}">
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <div class="info-prod">
    <h2><b>{{productsCar.nombre}}</b></h2>
    <p>Codigo de barra : {{productsCar.codigo}}</p>
    <ion-icon name="md-pricetag"></ion-icon><b> $ {{productsCar.precio}}</b>
    </div>
 </ion-item>

      <ion-item-options side="right">
                         <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="borrarCar(productsCar)">
                               Borrar
                         </button>
      </ion-item-options>

    </ion-item-sliding>
    <div *ngIf="!productsCar">No tiene productos en su carro...</div>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you initialise `productsCar` with an empty array you can check its length:

TS:

```
productsCar: any = [];
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="productsCar.length == 0">No tiene productos en su carro...</div>
```

Comment: You can also use `<div *ngIf="!productsCar.length ">...</div>`

Answer (score 0):

I actually came here to know how to do it... Tried the Andreas Grassmann solution and didn't work... try the original post and worked!

*ngIf="!vMyArray"